# Should I flag XY problem questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, xy-problem

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471741/how-to-include-file-php-for-moment) is a classic case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Should it be flagged? If so, how? It is a low quality question or is it unclear?

Comment: Don't flag it, instead prompt the OP to be more clear about their problem. To me it appears they are not a native english speaker, they may not be aware that they haven't asked a good question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, don't use moderator flags for this.

In general, moderator flags are for situations that cannot be handled by the community.  Answerable questions are answerable, even if the answer is "You're doing it wrong."

Comment: But the OP wasn't asking about using a *mod* flag in particular; the two suggestions he gave (LQ and unclear) are community-handled. Also, it seems worth pointing out that since the OP has 369 rep, he almost certainly doesn't know which flags are "moderator flags". In the UI as he sees it, it's entirely reasonably to assume that spam flags, LQ flags, closure flags and 'other' flags all go to the same place. Mods and high rep users assuming that low-rep users have more knowledge of the flagging system than they reasonably *could* have is a recurring mistake I've seen on MSO.

Comment: The verbiage that the OP is using ("low quality," "unclear") suggests that he has an adequate grasp of the terminology.