# A car with square wheels

Tags: discussion, xy-problem

If a question is posed

> How do I fit this square here on this here car so that it gives a smooth ride?

and it comes with all the requisites to be a valid SO question (description, code, error messages, bolts & wrenches), do I then answer

> Fit it like so and make sure you tighten the bolts properly

or do I start off by saying

> You can't possibly want that, so I'll assume you want a circular wheel instead and then you proceed like so...

In other words, should I consider—and possibly change—the context of the OP and give the answer cast in a specified context that makes more sense *to me*, or do I first point out to the OP that the context is shaky and that s/he better review that first and re-state the question?

Comment: Or first ask for clarification. I often see people answering too quickly (not necessarily referring to you). Maybe they're making a car that should drive up and down the stairs. OPs often forget to give context details that are so obvious to them they forget it's not obvious to others.

Comment: What makes you sure that the road intended to use isn't designed especially for square wheels?

Comment: Yes, it could of course also be a space car

Comment: ***Possibly*** related: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/163250).

Comment: @JensG most users asking about square car wheels actually need a bicycle with training wheels. If OP is absolutely positively certain they need square wheels, they can see that their question is contradictory and they will (or have to, anyway) explain properly why they are asking such a nonstandard question.

Comment: @CodeCaster: But isn't that what SO is about? Helping people out with issues that eventually migrate them from needing training wheels to doing the Tour de France?

Comment: You may direct them to [an episode of Mythbusters](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/square-wheels.htm)...

Comment: Yes, **a little knowledge is a dangerous thing**.  It is absolutely **hateful** when someone with (some limited) knowledge in a specialist field blurts out "Oh, you SHOULDN'T DO THAT!"

Comment: What if doing it the wrong way is outright dangerous, and you can't know whether it was wrong until it's too late? I don't have a car analogy, but a case in point is [cryptography](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptography). Most questions there show a lack of understanding of basic principles. Somebody wise once said that programming cryptography is like arming a bomb...

Comment: Topical for me, since I just answered one of those yesterday, by telling the guy he wanted round wheels instead. I try to be tactful when suggesting the round wheels. Too often I do find myself annoyed when ppl do that to me, so when asking for square wheels I try to explain WHY I want them square. ref [Proper way to copy database from /assets to app's private storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579910/proper-way-to-copy-database-from-assets-to-apps-private-storage)

Comment: Closely related: [Answering a question vs. solving a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17627)

Comment: If users knew how to ask good questions, volume on the site would decrease by about 90%.

Comment: No, no, it NEEDS to have square wheels so that it doesn't roll away when I park it on a hill.  Please read the question fully!  I do NOT WANT an answer involving circular wheels.

Comment: @DavidWallace I want to use all of my daily vote allowance on your comment

Comment: Even if you can provide sample of [car with square wheels](http://s1.developerslife.ru/public/images/gifs/3453ff3b-0cb0-43a6-a1fb-e49f2b12ff5f.gif) - then, please - do that carefully. You should do both things in that case - both provide example and explanation of why is this bad. You also may provide some alternative (that, usually, will improve the answer)

Comment: see also: [Should I flag questions w/ XY problem?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253605/should-i-flag-questions-w-xy-problem)

Comment: I MUCH prefer an answer of "Well if you really want to, do this, but we don't see square wheels much because they tear up the streets something awful so you might have meant round, I'd do that this way..."  I say it's a terrible omission to just answer a question when they are obviously not asking the question they intended (Especially when it might be dangerous to other drivers).

Comment: I mean, it's certainly possible to get a smooth ride using square wheels, you'd just need the right surface.

Comment: I recognize it's important to help guide people to the right solution when they may not be asking the right question, but I've also come across a lot of users on SE who seem to have no imagination, and are unwilling to answer even simple questions until the OP proves their use case. Since when did SE become a place where you have to provide a WHY before you can get the WHAT?

Comment: at least for me, (i can't speak for everyone,) I prefer to not answer a question unless i know my answer is the correct and best answer. I do this to avoid wasting my own time providing an answer I can't stand behind. For me to know this, the question needs to be specific enough that i can make that judgement. The more experience you have with a given subject, the more you know about the pitfalls and thus the more info you need to provide what you'd consider the best solution to avoid them.

Answer (score 278):

I'd ask them if their track is so very unusual that it necessitates square wheels.  In general, asking questions before condemning the message/messenger is useful and kind.  Underlying assumptions and prejudices sometimes inhibit our imagination.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Slammer!!! Me and my unimaginative skill set...

Comment: Very accurate pictures! My favorite answer so far in Meta!

Comment: Too few people ask questions for clarification and just assume you mean something else.  I +1 for questions before answers.

Comment: I am now wondering if including graphs/pics/videos generates 10x upvotes.

Comment: And as you don't know if A or B, toss a coin and close against the duplicate of A or B already. When OP answers the comment and you see that tossing the coin did miss, offer the other duplicate or re-open in case there ain't one.

Comment: Except answering like that will sound snarky *however*  you phrase it, and so you will fall foul of the new Code of Conduct.

Comment: @Raedwald Asking directed questions to get clarification has worked for me 100's of times - mostly in person, but also online. With a sincere desire to help, snarkiness is rarely perceived. Ofc, if help isn't the goal, slamming them with some severe Socratic Method is a cruel option. But why would anyone here want to do that?

Answer (score 66):

I normally do both.  First, I give a short clear explanation of how to accomplish what the OP appears to *want* to do with a reason why it is a better option.

Then, I answer the question the way it was asked.  I'll often put a disclaimer along the lines of "If you're sure you really want square wheels..."

You may also want to review the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/180564).

Comment: I would just say you should be very careful about assuming the person is an idiot/beginner and is falling in to a well-known "you shouldn't do that" situation in your specific field of expertise.  A good example is when experts ask questions about using goto (in sophisticated algorithms, say). You always get a few "undergraduate" clowns who heard somewhere that you "shouldn't use goto!" yelling about how they heard that you shouldn't use goto.

Comment: @JoeBlow In my experience, when the question is coming from an expert who wants to do something somewhat unorthodox, there are clear signs that is the case.  They'll either outright say "I know goto is not a good solution for many cases," or there question will make it obvious why goto is a good solution in their case.

Comment: @just.another.programmer yes that's what I think most of the "experts" would do, and I try to pretend to be an "expert" by doing that too.

Comment: **THIS**. Answer the actual question of how to do X. Then explain - gently and politely - why doing X is a bad approach if they're trying to achieve Y, and what a good approach is instead.

Comment: As an expert, I frequently get "You shouldn't do X" answers/comments that are annoying as hell. Just because I didn't spend half my question explaining WHY I'm doing "X" and that my IQ and expertise are enough to know that I want to do X and not Y, doesn't mean you should assume otherwise and answer with a smug - AND useless "Don't do X". Frequently, my asking about "X" is simply a distillation of a larger problem, or simply poking under the hood of a technology.

Comment: Sometimes you're also working with obnoxious upstream code you have no control over, so the question becomes a game of "how can I do this with this obnoxious limitation?" It's frustrating for both the person asking the question and the person answering, because both of then know the real answer is "you REALLY shouldn't do that", but the asker is stuck knowing they HAVE to do it in a really stupid way.

Comment: @dvk 90% of the time, the reason for an absence of an explanation of why the obvious is not being done is that the person *hasn't* thought about it - [if you *have*, you can save everyone's time (including your own) by saying so up front!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108070)

Answer (score 25):

Answering those kind of questions too early may prove fruitless in cases whereby the OP changes the question in a way that you didn't imagine, rendering your answer less ideal if not plain wrong.

Asking for clarification in the comments section would be my recommendation. There are cases whereby it's abundantly clear the OP has an XY problem, but applying this logic to all questions borders speculation.

Besides, doesn't this look sexy? :)

[image: sports car with square wheels]

[*Related forum post*](http://986forum.com/forums/387706-post26.html)

Comment: I think those tires might rub on the fenders a bit.

Comment: @Ellesedil It's only meant to look good, obviously :)

Comment: @Ellesedil they're just `static` wheels, that's all.

Comment: The wheels on the bus were not well thought out. The wheels on the bus were not well thought out. The wheels on the bus were not well thought out, by the engineer!

Answer (score 20):

Square wheel or [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/180564) questions are often easily answered. It always helps to have some **examples**. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623906/problems-with-streams-in-c-sharp) an old one, slightly edited for demonstration's sake:

> How can I reset a stream? Because the first time I want to count how many lines are there in the file, and then I want to read the lines. I need the lines in an array.
>
> ```
> using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
> {
>     int lineCount;
>     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
>     {
>         lineCount++;
>     }
>
>     string[] lines = new string[lineCount];
>
>     int i = 0;
>     string line;
>     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
>     {
>         lines[i++] = line;
>     }
> }
> ```

Actually I have reconstructed the question text and code entirely, as it was pulled out of OP using various comments.

The base question itself, *"How do I reset a stream in .NET"* was answered within 5 minutes. It also had been [years before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746092/do-i-need-to-reset-a-streamc-back-to-the-start), so looking at it like that it should have been closed as a duplicate instead of answered.

Please note the offending question is *answered* in that duplicate. This is how I think the duplicate system works. The *question* does not need to be the same, as long as the question asked is answered in that thread. The duplicate linked also is (for me) the top web search result on the query *"C# reset stream"*.

Apart from being a duplicate, as which it could have been closed, it clearly is an XY problem. Anyone with any programming experience will notice reading a file twice for first counting the lines and then actually reading the lines is a bit convoluted and will perform badly on larger files.

The actual question that should have been asked is *"Read all lines in file to array using .NET"*. Put that query in your favorite web search engine, and the top two results are [MSDN: File.ReadAllLines Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SO: What's the fastest way to read a text file line-by-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line).

Asking the proper question *will* get it answered, and usually before it becoming a question on SE.

Remember:

> give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime

By not properly reading and understanding the real question behind the question, but dumping an answer that seems to solve the most obvious problem, the answerer gets a few points and the asker can happily continue copypasting code. Both haven't learned anything.

The proper answer was ultimately given:

> Why not just read it into a `List<string>` and then build an array from that? Or more simply still, just call `File.ReadAllLines`:
>
> ```
>  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("TestFile.txt");
> ```

---

The **problems** addressable from this example and other experiences:

- Question askers may or may not have a clue to what they're doing. This may cause them to [ask the wrong question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Their experience level often is not clear from their profile, nor necessarily from their language as many non-native English speakers (such as me) take part.
- Question askers may have made a design decision earlier on which created the need for the question at hand. Preventing the design mistake could render the question obsolete. The mistake may or may not be fixable.
- Duplicate flags can be disputed in comments by users who don't see the the similarities, usually causing the question not to be closed. This can be fixed by revising reference questions.
- While comments are being exchanged (or not, especially new users will ask and run) about some things that *must* be cleared up before a proper answer can be given, users will post answers to their interpretations of questions without conforming their beliefs with OP.
- [A question-and-answer-game can be played in the comments, leading to actually multiple questions being asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments?cb=1), while a plain answer to the question may not answer the complete question. This requires effort from the commenter, and meanwhile answers giving a quick win are being posted, which should have been duplicate votes instead as they're unoriginal.

This all boils down to either the experience and lack thereof in askers and answerers, or not understanding that handing out fish by the dozens will leave you both hungry by the end of the week.

The **main problem I have** with users answering duplicate, too broad and XY questions causes is that **knowledge is spread out**. Yes, the askers are helped for now and the answerers get reputation, but more and more knowledge that may become outdated or otherwise needs maintenance is spread amongst more and more answers, and unhelpful or plain incorrect answers are less likely to be noticed because of the sheer volume of new content on the site.

Users with the appropriate voting rights and tools *and* experience are unable to keep up with the stream of questions that should be closed or redacted.

Experience does not mean reputation, by the way. [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke?tab=answers) hardly ever gets an upvote while he is *the* HTTP authority on this network and "Principal Software Design Engineer" (WinAPI designer) [Raymond Chen's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen?tab=activity&sort=comments) are often ignored.

---

What possible **solutions** are there to that problem?

Other solutions I've read about on Meta:

- [The ostrich approach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions) ([not really](http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/22zt65/til_that_there_has_never_been_a_single_recorded/), though).
- Closevoting.
- Downvoting.

Neither solve the real problem.

There is one silly solution I've been thinking of lately, which could become a feature request later to vote on appropriately, consider this my sales pitch:

> Questions from certain users* should not be posted open, but temporarily** put on hold, so it won't attract any quick answers***, as such answers most likely are duplicate  anyway. During this 'timeout', users can use all tools available to them (edit, flag, definitely close, except reopen) and request clarification using comments.
>
> The 'reopen' action should be only available to a select group of users****, enabling them to 'green light' a question before the automatic on hold-timeout expires.
>
> This will cause less questions to be *necessary* to be asked and answered, freeing resources to [find and answer the really interesting questions again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions). It will also provide an incentive to find and polish reference questions.

Implementation details, subject to change:

```
*: new users or users with a bad question history.
**: for example the first 15 minutes.
***: users can type a draft answer, which they'll have to explicitly submit
     after the question unlocks. 
****: moderators and another group of users.
```

This new group of users will have to be responsible for redirecting the askers of duplicate, too broad or XY questions to resources the asker can use to narrow down or even solve their issue. Other users can then take those users' behavior to learn how one should properly interpret a question and act accordingly.

It's about setting an example, for which I think for now most high-rep users apply.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster for this elaborate expose, going well beyond the initial issue, but placing it in the wider context of Q&A quality. I concur that a threshold for entering a question, especially for new users, may be a useful feature. Having been around on SO for a mere two months I cannot reflect upon the good ol' days but with my BBS and Usenet upbringing - yes, that old - it is not hard to establish that access is too easy, judging by the flood of questions that reek of no analysis, no research, no effort. A "no pain, no gain" approach might remedy (some of) that.

Answer (score 10):

Personally I tell the OP that he/she better go for a different approach which spares him/her time and nerves in the future. We also have to think about future visitors that may use a better approach too then when reading the answers. Since we like to build a knowledge base of **professional** answers we do not only want to help beginners fixing their horrible code. Tell them what's wrong.

Sometimes I also directly answer the question if for instance the OP tells me he/she can't change the database structure to fix the problem. But leaving a note for a better solution is always good.

Comment: -1. As a professional and an expert, sometimes (or rather, almost always) I ask questions on how to do "X" for a reason, not because I don't know enough to not be aware of "Y". It's OK to ask a clarifying polite comment "Have you considered Y" and then, in case of a negative, to answer this way, but NOT OK to blythely assume incompetence.

Answer (score 7):

If the question is asked "in good faith" and has enough information, so that it looks like it can be rescued, I try to read the OP's mind and answer the question I think is really being asked (and explain why). That's the essence of being a good teacher: *improve* the question as you answer it.

But if the question is just poor quality, I mark it for closure (unclear or not enough info) and downvote it.

Comment: In fact, I pride myself on my ability to do this - and I also upvote other people who do it, and I sometimes comment to encourage them, as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23594990/341994 Just a small example, but my point is, this answerer "read the OP's mind" and got to the heart of what the _real_ problem was even though the OP didn't.

Comment: Here's an example of my own: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23001020/341994 I felt that the question was wrongly pounced on and snarkily pushed back and downvoted and closed by others, who looked at what the OP _said_ (badly) but didn't think about what he might _mean_. I did the latter and so was able to give him a sense of what he was after even though he hadn't used any of the right words. (By the way, the moderator 0x7ffffff seems to me particular guilty of this sort of premature impatient closure: the question was phrased poorly, but was quite legit and rescuable.)

Answer (score 5):

It's a judgment call of course. Answers on Stack Overflow always have to walk the line between being too direct one one side and thus "answer but not teach", and too invasive on the other side and thus not "just answering the damn question".

Often I find that it's quite possible to tell how where your answer should go on this spectrum from the way a question is presented. If the asker knows the field and needs something unusual, they will usually have the wits to explain briefly the motivation for their request and why the "standard" approaches don't suit.

On the other hand, it is very unlikely that someone who *doesn't* know the field actually needs an unusual solution and just happens to stumble across a problem where standard techniques don't apply. And *even then* such a person would be best advised to develop some understanding of the field first before embarking on something unconventional.

As others have suggested, you may very well use the comments to get clarification, but you can also get a decent signal on whether you should start working on a question right away, or perhaps just walk away, just from the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

If it's clearly a poorly thought out, incompletely conceived, inaccurate, or uninformed question, I usually answer their first question with whatever assumptions I need to make it work as if it were an engineering contest question -- where you are given limited resources or inappropriate tools or methods, or limited to some specifically non-use item.

I give them something slightly over-board or outrageous, but essentially correct.  "First, you're going to need an infinite number of square wheels..."

It may not be fair, but my first attempt is to derail their train of thought and then sneak a look at their map to see where they're going.

After they ask what I'm on about, I get to ask exactly what did they meant by their question -- what exactly are they trying to do, where did they think they were headed. We proceed from there on foot if necessary.

Answer (score -5):

You should definitely and solely answer with second variant only.

But there is a strong high-brow lobby on meta, who seldom answer questions on SO but prefer to teach others how to answer. They will tell you that you should answer the first variant. And then they go and flag your answer with most ridiculous comment "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post". Most people here cannot grasp any idea of abstraction. And their only idea on answer is a strictly literal and direct one.

In a way, it's the essence of Stack Overflow, though. This site is not for helping people - it is for answering questions.

Comment: Many questions are way too broad and demonstrate this behavior. A question like "How do I create a database table for a user when they register?" should be closed. It's two questions at once ("How to run code when a user registers" and "How tob create a database table from code"). Besides being closed for being too broad, it is a really silly question and shows a bad design. If that question gets answered, you can expect OP back in a day or two with a question like "How to dynamically add tables to Entity Framework" or equivalent follow-up questions inherent to their bad design.

Comment: I disagree with your last statement - it is over simplified. The goal here is not to help one specific person but rather to provide answers that can be helpful to more people than only the OP.

Comment: In some situations you don't have the luxury to change Y, so an answer with a solution Z that solves X, may not be helpful at all for the OP.

Comment: @YCS: Why do you constantly whine about the site and still use it?

Comment: Right on the money! I've had some really very helpful advice on this site but it is always a struggle to adhere to the silly rules that seem to support only one type of question.
SO is mostly for silly questions you can google anyway. Just look at the top score questions. How do I type Hello World in C? and et cetera.
If you ask something more complicated - that requires discussion and the SO system does not facilitate discussion - just wanking with the format of the question all the time.

It's especially bad in niche topics, where the few moderators gang up on defenseless people to nitpick