# Unclear Questions vs. Wrong Way to Solve a Problem

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

When a user asks the question to solve a problem of his/her, is it important that the **description** of the subproblem is unclear or the **approach** to the problem is right or wrong? ([XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem))

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716304/detecting-the-repetition-in-string-object-and-removing-the-remaining), I asked a question which I think is pure clear. Describes my problem very well. Title is consistent with the question. But if you check the comments, all the commenters say that my approach is wrong and they need more detail.

I do not want to give any more detail. Even if I wanted to, it makes no sense! Because my **question** is written in detail.

I think most of the users suffer from this situation. Even though the question is asked clearly, since the approach to the problem related to the question is wrong, it gets downvoted.

Is it a resonable downvote when the question is downvoted because of this?

Comment: SO is not your personal help-desk.  Your problem and its resolution must be useful to somebody else that googles it some day.

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=bPh3U77OAc3c8geQqYD4Cg#q=find+repeating+characters+in+a+string+java+and+removing

Comment: See also: [A car with square wheels - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels)

Answer (score 7):

*Every* downvote (modulo voting fraud) is a "reasonable downvote."  There are no rules from higher authority denoting how we should vote, because the community itself decides that - by **voting**.

As for your specific question, your *input* and *expected output* is clear.  That's presumably why it's still open¹ - it is answerable, for some definition of answerable at least.

Voting score indicates nothing more than the community's general estimation of the value of a post.  By downvoting, the community could be saying any number of things:

- This question could not possibly help any future readers
- As stated, the goal of your code is to "reduce the rounding errors", but by implementing it you will greatly *increase* your rounding errors
- This second point was made repeatedly by several well-regarded posters, but you stubbornly ignored the advice every time

Were I a betting man, I'd put a $20 on the last one being the driving factor.  You say in the comments:

> I have a problem and I want to solve it this way. Right way or not, let me experience it.

Your "experience" in general here should probably be closer to horror and revulsion that you were about to unleash some code-abomination-from-the-abyss of a rounding function on the world, and gratitude that they saved you and the rest of us from such a fate.

Or you could plant your foot and say "but I was *clear!*" and see how far that gets you.  Up to you.

---

¹This may change, since there is clearly no way to answer your stated goal of "reducing the rounding error" with your current approach.  Thus, unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Because my goal is not to reduce the rounding error but doing what I asked. Consider this as a programming assignment. Just I have written in comments, values go beyond the capacity of double. Therefore, for the sake of preventing future big rounding errors, I prefer to have them at the beginning. It is nearly 1200 lines of code and I have to post all of them to make sense.

Comment: I didn't make that goal up, I was using your exact words from the thread.  Anyway you don't need to make your case to *me*, you should have done that to the commenters in the thread.  At this point you've moved the goalposts enough times that it's not worth anyone's time to get you to see reason on the matter, which is probably why your question got closed.

Answer (score 6):

You have posted a question because you need help with a problem **you are having**. In general, you are more likely to get that help if you cooperate with those who want to help you and are asking for clarification in order to do so.

Having read the question and comments I don't see anything unreasonable there. I just see a bunch of people trying to help you despite your best efforts to prevent them doing so.

> Here, I asked a question which I think is pure clear

It may be clear to you, but it obviously isn't to others reading the question. They don't have your detailed knowledge of **your** problem.

> I do not want to give any more detail

Then you are less likely to get a useful answer, your call.

> Even if I wanted to, it makes no sense! Because my question is written in detail.

Detail != clarity

> Is it a resonable downvote when the question is downvoted because of this?

Yes, without a doubt. Hover your mouse over a downvote arrow to see why.

If you want an answer to your problem answer the questions from those people who are doing their best to help you. Remember, they are not paid to do so and are at liberty to move on and ignore you if you don't.

In fact, if you do not provide clarification your question is likely to be closed as off topic:-

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: I still don't understand which part is unclear. Noone said "this is unclear" in comments or so.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because anyone reading that question will have been repeating "Why?" in their head at every line of it.

There is nothing wrong with a controversial question, but experienced users generally want to make sure that what is being asked actually is what is required (XY) before putting their effort in it. The statement that they'll need to read another 1200 lines of code in order to understand your question only emphasizes this.

If you then refuse to answer the comments, downvotes can indeed occur.

Comment: I am doing trilateration in 3d. The reason I don't include this information in the question is actually this is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

2 points:

1. First, you got "XY" comments precisely because you innocently posted the "Y". You should have simply asked how to detect N digits in a row, and posted your attempted code of how you did it.
2. I actually completely disagree with the other 2 answers. The question is crystal clear and in no way useless. It had **too much** information (reasons for why the answer was needed) but the solution to that is editing out extras, not closing.
3. And "not wanting to listen to comments about XY problem" is in no way a legitimate reason to downvote. You can't DO anything about it, sadly.

   Yes, downvotes can be done for any reason, but there are guidelines and the spirit of why they were instituted and "user doesn't want to hear that his approach to solving a problem is wrong" ain't one of them.

   As has always been repeatedly stressed on MSO, **VOTE FOR THE POST, NOT THE USER**.

Comment: @CodeCaster - it helpful to me (It's probably a bit basic, but I'm a Java newbie, who's being forced to work on Java now). So your "anyone else" assumption is wrong. I totally agree that it's the wrong algo to do rounding, but what I was interested in was specific user question of how to do certain things in Java, regardless of his end goal.

Comment: The specific question as was stated was not likely to be useful for anyone else. _"How to find repeating characters in a string"_ is.

Comment: @CodeCaster - that WAS his underlying question. The rest was useless explaining of WHY he was detecting

Comment: With your edits, I agree that this is a clear and completely suitable SO question. I _definitely_ agree with your bit about "guidelines and the spirit" of downvoting -- one _can_ vote for any reason, but that doesn't mean one _should_. I can see, however, that other users might honestly think that the question was not useful or clear, given the pre-edit confusion.