# Answering question at hand vs. Suggesting a better solution

Tags: discussion

Let us say OP asked a question that only requires syntax correction. Though it works, the approach was not "best practice".

Stacker A posted a direct solution to the question and fixed the syntax.

Stacker B posted a best practice approach (but does not technically answer the posted question).

Which answer must be marked accepted and why?

Comment: The OP can accept either one. There are no rules regarding that. But if you provide an answer which does both (answer the question *and* provide an alternate solution), then it'll be useful to everybody and probably have the greatest chance of being accepted.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually the OP/Question Author. I was torn which answer to accept. I decided to accept the syntax correction (for technically answering the question) and upvoted the best practice answer.

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of [A car with square wheels](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels), or if not that one, than of the many other similar [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type meta questions to be found here.

Comment: Neither answer *must* be accepted. The OP is free to accept either answer, or no answer at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither.  Acceptance doesn't mean much except, "The person that asked this question found it to be the most helpful."

If it's a matter of correctness versus a matter of "just fixing the problem", then it really depends on the question asked.

- If it comes across as something that's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/175248), then the more full answer would be of more value to future users.
- If it really was a matter of a simple typo in terms of syntax, then I'd likely elect to close it before doing anything else - only in a handful of cases have I seen syntax questions that are actually applicable to a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

The question author is allowed to mark whatever answer they want.  They *must* do nothing.

Other readers are also free to vote however they want on either post, based on whether they personally feel that the post in question is useful or not.