# Is that question a duplicate or not? Dupehammer fight

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, dupehammer

I think the question [Setting an Array Element as an Object Property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28720507/1529630) is a duplicate of [How to create an object property from a variable value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2241875/1529630).

The only difference is that the second one wants to use the value of a variable as the property name, while the first one wants to use a value in an array.

Therefore, I used my dupehammer to close it.

But Michael Berkowski used his dupehammer to reopen.

However, I'm still convinced it's a duplicate.

What happens now? I have only found [the following](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/1529630), which doesn't seem much serious:

> If you get in a fight with someone over whether a question should be
>   closed, moderators will be notified and they'll <s>hit everyone with
>   hammers</s> lock everything down and tell you to go home.

Is it a duplicate or not?

Comment: Two gold badgers, one hammer?  Oh, wait... wrong film.  Two gold badgers enter, one leaves...

Comment: @MichaelT: Leave the poor badgers alone, even if they are golden...

Comment: Why are you so gung-ho to close it as a duplicate in the first place. Whatever happened to a little benefit of the doubt?

Comment: this is kind of a duplicate of: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286785/are-can-i-solve-problem-x-with-y-duplicates-of-how-do-i-solve-problem-x?cb=1

Comment: I think it might be useful to allow 'dupehammer' to cast a vote, to build a consensus.

Comment: @race_carr. In general (dunno about this specific case), closing duplicate questions early (if they actually are dupes) is a *good* thing: rather than waiting for an answer, you're pointed toward an answer which already exists.

Comment: Wonder why you don't just dupe your hammer to get duped dupehammers? This way one could easily outhammer the other dupe ... ;-)

Comment: The ***default*** behavior in this site should be to shrug it off and let the question stand.  And here's the problem with SO in general, folks think that because there are a lot of members that this somehow validates all power hungry behavior.  Well understand this for once: OF COURSE STACKOVERFLOW HAS A LOT OF MEMBERS----IT GOT THAT WAY BY APPEALING TO THE VERY WORST IN HUMAN NATURE.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Those indeed are not duplicates. The question specifically asked about using a variable value for a property name in an *object literal*, while your suggested duplicate does deal with creating variable-named properties on objects in general.

However, I've thrown my own hammer in the match and closed it as a duplicate of *[Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242/1048572)*, which I personally figured to be the best post on this topic long ago and since used as a close target [very often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2274242?lq=1). Admittedly, we don't have an exceptionally-good community-wiki canonical question for this problem; maybe we should create one. Or merge some of the good answers into a single location.

Comment: OK, I was assuming that setting the property in the object literal was also desirable for [How to create object property from variable value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2241875/1529630) because of the code snippet in the question, but it's true the text is a bit more general.

Comment: Then, should questions like [Javascript: creating object with dynamic keys](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19837916/1529630), which is closed as a dupe of [How to create object property from variable value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2241875/1529630), be dupes of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242/1529630) instead? Maybe the titles should be edited to make the difference more clear.

Comment: @Oriol: Isn't it already? But yes, editing titles is probably the first step to better duplicates.

Comment: Oh, true, it's closed right. Don't know why I thought the opposite, maybe I swapped the tabs in the browser or something, haha.

Comment: @Oriol: Yeah, having multiple tabs with multiple closed and unclosed and canonical questions and different close targets can be confusing. I really had to triple-check your comment, it's quite possible that I had closed with a "wrong" duplicate - has happened to me a few times.

Answer (score 4):

It should be kept closed as a generic duplicate of:

[How to create an object property from a variable value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875)

... or any other question that explains how to use a variable to set a property on an object.

---

For me, minor differences do not warrant a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

They are not a duplicates. Because when you define an object in JavaScript you can use variables as the properties and not array indexes, the second question specifically ask that.

```
var obj = {array[i]: 'hello' }; // Does not work
var obj = {variable: 'hello' }; // Does work
```

The first question does not explain why the first case does not work, and from the example a variable can not be used in such a case. An answer in the second question states: *"a valid property name cannot have [ or ] in it."*. Which clearly is not present in any of the answer in the first question.

Comment: And yet the older question has answers using both of the approaches described in the newer question, and only one of many answers to either question  (and currently the lowest score of all of them) use the approach you've described here.  Do the proposed duplicate does in fact provide suitable answers to the case described in the new question, even if every single answer isn't applicable.

Comment: Yes, `{variable: 'hello' }` doesn't throw. But I wouldn't say that it works, because the property is named `"variable"` instead of the value of the variable `variable`. That's a complete different thing than setting the property name to the value contained in a variable or array.

Comment: @Oriol I understand that, my main point is just to show that the first case is throwing an error while the second one doesn't. And the reasoning is not explained is not explained in the other question.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me that the system is working exactly as it should. You closed the question, but someone else didn't agree with you and reopened it. If it's not an obvious dupe (as evinced by the reopen), then it should not be closed as a dupe. Or, at the very least, it should be closed as a duplicate of a more appropriately similar question, as @Bergi did.