# Should I vote to close a question that has no clear answer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, xy-problem

This is not clear to me at all.

Here is an example: *trying to do something with CSS that can only be done in PHP*. I can't tell you how often questions like these pop up, but I feel at a loss regarding whether or not to vote to close.

If voting to close is the right way to go, then can someone please enlighten me regarding which vote to close flag should I be using for these kinds of questions?

To be clear: I am **not** asking about questions which can possibly be:

1. Duplicate of.
2. Spam.
3. Rude or Abusive.
4. Very low quality.
5. In need of moderator attention.

Comment: You use the duplicate flag when you feel that a question should be closed as a duplicate...I fail to see the confusion here...

Comment: It's still *entirely* unclear what you're asking?  Are you actually asking what close reason you should use for a question you think is a duplicate, because the answer is pretty obvious, close it as a duplicate.  If you're asking something else, it's entirely unclear what it is.

Comment: @Servy when I saw the question: 1. nothing had happened regarding duplicate. 2. After some research I refreshed the page and the question was gone, completely. So I did not see it being duplicated at any point in time. Yet that is not the reason why I asked this question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Much better, but there's still some points you should clarify. Can you find a post that isn't deleted and represents the kind of post you're talking about? The example you give in italics could be closed for multitudes of reasons, depending on how the question is asked.

Comment: @Kendra Sorry for being overly broad, I wished I had live examples of this but I currently do not.

Comment: Another reason not to close a question because the task is impossible: It's only impossible *right now*. I've seen plenty of old HTML/CSS questions where the original answer was "You can't (without JavaScript)" but the current answer is, "Here's how to do this with HTML5/CSS3".

Comment: duplicate of [A car with square wheels](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels)

Comment: @gnat that's a pretty good question/answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Here is an example: trying to do something with CSS that can only be done in PHP. I can't tell you how often questions like these pop up, but I feel at a loss for choices regarding vote to close flag.

I may take some flak for this, but... is closing the right option here?

If it can't be done... **say so** as an ANSWER and explain why.

A simple declarative "This is not possible with CSS" (from your example) is your primary answer.

You might *then* expand to say, *"an alternative might be..."*

Example from my own experience: [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433476/how-to-limit-element-heights-to-specific-values-stepped-based-on-content/34433614#34433614)

Comment: I can see how that can be the case, then you'd work with the person who asked the question to help fix their actual issue. In that case, is a close flag not the right way to go or are there cases (in your experience) in which you might say, yes it is irrelevant to answer, instead vote to close?

Comment: It would depend on the actual question. If what they want is clearly impossible then a simple NO is usually enough, I might do this as a comment (and find a suitable close reason...perhaps a custom one) but an answer is searchable and might help future users where a closed/delete question may not.

Comment: see that makes a lot of sense, its better to explain why said questions can't be done than to simply vote to close due to other reasons, or even pressuring the person who asked the question to delete the question. I might even modify this question to say something more relevant to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed - See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433476/how-to-limit-element-heights-to-specific-values-stepped-based-on-content/34433614#34433614

Comment: Excellent that illustrates the whole problem in one shot, well done

Comment: @AGE Keep in mind that if a question _is_ off topic and therefore is correct to close under one of the close reasons (for instance, in this case "unclear" could easily fit one of these questions) you shouldn't forgo a correct closing of an off topic question just to answer it with "this can't be done." If the question just asks to do something impossible but doesn't fit any off topic reasons... Then it's not off topic and shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @Kendra following your comments, it shouldn't be closed and instead it should be dealt with in the manner that Paulie_D described, at least to the benefit of future readers

Comment: @AGE As long as it's on topic, yes. Paulie_D's example question, for instance, is on topic and therefore shouldn't be closed. A vague/unclear description of what one wants to do without an example of how they already know how to do it with other technology would be fit for closing as "unclear" and should _not_ be answered. If it's that unclear, it likely wouldn't help future visitors. If the latter question is later edited to be on topic, it can always be reopened and answered then.

Comment: @Kendra that might be a solid answer to the question regarding whether or not to vote to close depending on the question clarity and closing conditions :-)

Comment: @AGE I think I'll let Paulie_D decide if he'd like to edit that in first. If not, I'd be more than happy to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Kendra I'm happy for you to add your own answer...no harm in having differing / clarifying viewpoints on Meta.

Comment: @Kendra, I did ask whether or not a question should be closed. Even though I believe Paulie_D answered my core issue, this question is multi faceted so it would only add value to answer it in as many correct ways as possible

Answer (score 5):

For on-topic, non-duplicate questions, [Paulie_D's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314104/2607247) is perfectly correct. No need to close a question just because the answer isn't what the OP was hoping for.

However, don't take that to mean you should forgo closing an *off-topic* question just because you can answer with "This is impossible." No matter what the question is, or how easy to answer or interesting it is, if the question is off-topic for the site, it should be closed and not answered.

For the questions you're talking about with your example, they could very easily be unclear:

> I want to assign a value using only CSS and no Javascript.

That question, for instance, would be unclear. A value to what, exactly? Granted, that's not what CSS is for, so the answer is easy and quick regardless of what they want to assign a value to. But the question still fits the "unclear" close reason, and should be closed rather than answered.

Questions like the example in Paulie_D's answer are good, on-topic questions, however. You shouldn't try to force a close reason on a question if it doesn't fit. Answers saying you can't do something *and* showing you a different way to handle what you want are great and useful. Not to mention that, as mentioned in [BSMP's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314102/should-i-vote-to-close-a-question-that-has-no-clear-answer#comment290985_314102) there could come a day (or a change in technology) where what the OP wants to do *is* suddenly possible with the tools they wish to use. Closing a good, on-topic question about it prevents new solutions available due to changes in technology from being posted.