# What to do when your question is based on a factually incorrect premise?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question on stackoverflow which got upvoted once:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304353/flask-sqlalchemy-marshmallow-unexpected-progammingerror-on-autoflush

However, I now realize it is based on a factually incorrect premise.

(The statement "ie: there is no explicitly uncommitted transaction data to fault" is simply wrong.)

What should I do to correct this?

Should I do this in an edit, a comment, an answer, or should I attempt to delete the question itself?

Comment: It's still a question, you could answer it with "Obviously there is an incorrect premise in the question ...". However, if you find that you posed a particularly useless question (negative score would be a strong hint) just delete it (but most probably it would be deleted automatically anyway). Rarely, it could still be a useful question, e.g. if the incorrect premise is a common one.

Comment: [A car with square wheels](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels)?

Comment: Ignore facts and apply for office

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should edit your question.

If someone had answered your question based on that premise, you should comment on their answer indicating your error. But so far you don't have any answers so it's not a problem at all.

If your edit drastically changes the content of the question to the point that it barely even resembles the original question, I'd suggest deleting your question and writing a new one.

Comment: OK thanks. Since the question seems to make little sense without the false premise, I'm just going to go and delete it.

Comment: I think it's okay to leave it there as documentation, as long as the accepted answer explains the reason why the premise is false and how that impacts people with the same problem. Other folks might make the same fallacy, after all.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a common misconception e.g., attempting to extract arbitrary data from XML/HTML documents using regular expressions and you can't find the exact duplicate for your question then keep it as is—it may help other people with a similar wrong belief.

If the error is rather unique e.g., a typo and therefore useless for future visitors then edit/delete the question unless it invalidates existing answers.

The main purpose of a Stack Overflow question is to help future visitors from google with a similar problem.