# Should such a question be voted for closing?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

My question is this: [Why doesn't my instance get deallocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400390/why-doesnt-my-instance-get-deallocated)

It's a very childish misunderstanding. Yet it's a very pure, well defined question. Anyone who would have a similar mistake can benefit from this (noob) misunderstanding, its comments and answer(s)

I mean is that it's not of the type of question where if you had just searched enough and seen another code and paste it you're code would work. It's something beyond what you see (The code works, rather what's happening about the memory under the hood are unknown to a noob like me).

So should I delete the question? Close it? Or just leave it be?

Comment: Related: [What to do when your question is based on a factually incorrect premise?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340223/6214222)

Comment: I'm closing my own question, though I found the [non-accepted answer from J.F. Sebastian](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340332/5175709) more related :D