# How to tackle a "not even wrong" question?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

I sometimes see questions that cannot be answered reasonably, because the author's assumptions are wrong: [exhibit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42117524/223424), [exhibit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42116515/223424).

After some discussion in comments, I'd like to vote to close such questions, because the author should rethink the assumptions, re-formulate the question, and then the question might have a correct answer.

Is this a right approach? If so, what should be the closing vote's reason? "Unclear what you are asking" does not seem quite like the right one: it's clear what the author is asking, but a correct answer just cannot be given.

Comment: [A car with square wheels](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels)?

Comment: @gnat: A car with square wheels can definitely be made to run smoothly, by adapting the road. What I'm asking about is more "How do I best make a right turn in a car with square wheels on a normal highway? The car becomes unstable." I cannot answer about the proper right turn technique. I need to address the square wheels issue first, but it's _not what the question is asking about_. Hence my problem.

Comment: @dorukayhan: Thank you, it seems to be it.

Comment: I think there's a line between *"what you're literally asking for would require X, Y and Z [demo implementation here]; but this is probably not what you want in the real world as you can see"* and *"this is so far off there really isn't any answer to what you're asking"*. One of them is answerable, even if the answer may not be what OP expects, and the other probably is *too broad* or *unclear*.