# A well defined question, but maybe the wrong one

Tags: discussion, xy-problem

Sometimes there is a well defined question; there's a good answer to it, everyone is happy. But it "smells". The question stands on a weird base or anti-pattern. Maybe the question should be changed to the origin of the problem.

For example, [How to modify this JSON in Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0ku7.png). In this question, someone asks how to convert a JSON property from an array (which is supported by the JSON format) to a comma separated string. Of course there's a good answer to it (use `join`), and everyone is on a race to give it. But the question itself, does it make sense?

I'm not saying a question like that has no meaning on its own, an of course, maybe it's not as 'smelly' as I think, but it should be discussed - and the comments usually don't help, because a good answer comes, and everyone wants to answer to get some points.

I see this a lot. People are answering the 'literal' (sorry for the abuse of this word) question instead of going deeper.

What do you think *we* should do?

### Edit:

This question was flagged as a duplicate of [A car with square wheels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels). I believe it's similar, but what I was looking for was something different.

What I asked was as community, not as an individual. And going further, maybe someone can think of a feature for stackoverflow that might help. This was the intent of this discussion. Sorry for not being clear.

For example, here are some bad ideas from the top of my head:

- Flag a question as a 'square' , and until the questions (about the question) are not answered and/or the question is not edited no reputation points are given or even taken (this might be bad because it's not objective, only the person with the problem actually knows what was the original problem)
- Give reputation (similar to bounty) for someone for refining the 'square' question and answering the comments (this is bad because it's too vague, cannot think of a healthy mechanism).
- Flag a question as a 'square' which means it cannot be answered for 24 hours, only comments until everything is sort out (this is bad because the answer for the well defined question has value, it's a shame to miss it)
- Give it a name (like x-y, square - no feature, just the within the community) and "rally" anyone in the community who sees these type of questions to ask as many questions as they can and hope the person in-charge will answer and will be convinced that something is not right (it's not that bad, it's just similar to what we see today)
- Flag this question/answer as 'square' will give a warning to the viewer (when reading the question or the answer):  "**WARNING: this question/answer might be a case of a car with square wheels**"

Comment: Mention [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Cool.. didn't know it has a name. But it's still an unresolved issue. Because in the end, the one who asked the question decides. If there was a way to 'label' the question as XY, people would might do something different

Comment: But the problem could be nobody *recognizes* it as an X-Y problem. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27669252/2564301) is a recent one that discussed options in the comments until an answer pointed out it was the wrong question.

Comment: see also: [Should I flag questions w/ XY problem?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253605/should-i-flag-questions-w-xy-problem)