# Is closing XY problem trollish?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, xy-problem

The meta question: [Should I flag questions w/ XY problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253605/should-i-flag-questions-w-xy-problem) suggest that we do not flag XY problem.

Would flagging a question like this with XY problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128920/nltk-not-recognizing-a-named-entity?noredirect=1#comment59917451_36128920 constitute as trolling?

The OP of the question had use tool X on task Z and asked the question on why tool X don't solve task Y.

The author has deleted the question and say that I have been trolling but I'm not sure about it. I guess I would say that I'm trying to keep the standards on stackoverflow but am I wrong? Should this question be undeleted and answered properly?

BTW, I am accused of trolling the same OP on other questions too but I'm not sure about it. Is there a way to check which questions of his I've voted to close? And if they're really closed after community votes, am I really trolling him?

Comment: Your comment doesn't seem troll-ish to me, I suspect this is a reaction to something else. Editing the question to reply seems wrong though, maybe try chatting with the user instead.

Comment: Only you can know whether you took those actions with the intent of irritating the post author, as opposed to because you honestly felt it was the proper course of action.  We could potentially discuss whether or not the post merits closure, but we can't tell you whether you flagged the post to troll him or not.

Comment: It's a deleted question so only users above 10k can see it.

Comment: Why did you edit a lengthy diatribe about trolling *into the question*?

Comment: And you didn't actually even vote to close the question...

Comment: I did, then i retract.

Comment: @alvas Even though you think the question merits closure?

Comment: I guess, he was right in that i can explain properly rather than to post the comment on XY problem.

Comment: You gave a very simple, easy to understand explanation what happened.  The questioner instantly understood why he asked the wrong question.  But he's a graceless fool that blamed *you* for that mishap, trying to slight you by accusing you to be a troll.  And deleted his now useless question.  Do not over-react, this is poor behavior on the questioner's part and violates SO's prime directive.  Trying to "repair" it does not help at all.

Comment: Possibly the OP saw the comment `The OP doesn't not understand the nature of the function he's using, it's an XY problem (xyproblem.info).` I put when flagging the question thinking that only moderators see the comment. It's partly my fault too, I guess.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First off, I think there's a better way to phrase your criticism than

> The OP doesn't not understand the nature of the function he's using, it's an XY problem (xyproblem.info).

That comes off as an insult to the capabilities of the poster. There are much better ways of pointing out what might be wrong with the question.

However, your edits were completely inappropriate:

[image]

and totally baffling. Why in the world would you do that? If they weren't already upset at the tone of your comments, vandalizing their question is a surefire way to anger someone.

I recommend not doing that again.