# Should a well asked question be closed if it won't be useful to future readers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534129/convert-foreach-to-lambda/50534203#50534203) in which the OP wants to change their implementation of a task.

> Just started with Lambda in c# and I got stumbled by this.How can I
>   convert following code block to lambda expression, adding all the
>   values in headers get added to DefaultRequestHeaders.
>
> ```
> var client = new HttpClient();
> foreach (var header in headers)
> {
>     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Name, header.Value);
> }
> ```

The question itself is clear. While it doesn't include what type `headers` is, everything else is there (and I don't think including the type really changes the answer). It is pretty much an MVCE and minor improvements on the OP's end wouldn't change the result. The problem (for those of you who don't use C#) is that OP's current implementation is already about as good as it can be, and asking to change it to what the OP wants would be an abuse of lambda expressions (it would in no way improve the OP's current implementation, just the opposite if anything).

The question ended up getting an answer that provided the worse implementation, just for the sake of doing so. The OP then accepted this poor answer. While the answer does *technically* answer the question, it cannot be considered useful since it is a worse implementation than what the OP already has. In addition, both the answer and question are in no way helpful for future readers.

The question is not unclear or too broad. Looking over the off-topic options, none of them really seemed to fit. The question isn't about general hardware or software, has nothing to do with anything network related, isn't looking for an off-site resource, and it is (mostly) an MVCE.

The only two flags that I thought might apply are

1. Opinion based, since it can be said that what the OP is asking for would directly result in lower quality than what they already have.
2. Off-topic - problem can no longer be reproduced (since the OP doesn't really have a "problem" in the first place).

I feel like both of these would be rejected though. Would a mod flag be better or should I stick to one of the other flags? Or am I totally off base and this question is fine for the site?

Comment: Opinion based because in your opinion what they are asking for is a bad idea, I have not heard that justification yet.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  It's a creative argument.

Comment: It is a "I've got a hammer, but can't find the nail" question.  The answerer provided him one, the commenter (itsme86) provided the truth.  That "don't do it" is very rarely appreciated at SO is one of its tragedies.  Feel free to provide the truth yourself.

Comment: To put what Tiny Giant and Hans Passant are saying in another way: [XY questions are not off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322992/2751851), and it is perfectly legitimate to answer them by addressing X while questioning the need for Y.

Comment: What do you mean by *"What should a well asked question be closed"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Updated title.

Answer (score 8):

> The question is not unclear or too broad. Looking over the off-topic options, none of them really seemed to fit.

This is a very, very strong signal that you ***shouldn't*** be looking to close the question.  If you can't think of a justification for the question to be *closed*, then you shouldn't flag it for closure.

Feel encouraged to vote it down if you feel like it's poorly researched, but even then I would question that; this feels like a question which someone has asked for specific help and guidance on and isn't horribly broad or overreaching in its intent.

Comment: I agree that the question was well asked, I didn't down vote it because of that. I do feel like it will in no way be productive though (both for the OP and for future readers). Does that mean it is still ok to have on the site?

Comment: @Sudsy1002:  I cannot stress this enough.  **If you cannot find a reason to close the question, don't shoehorn one in.** If you don't think it's useful then that would merit a downvote.

Comment: I can agree with that, but what answer would be acceptable for the OP's question then? Should you give the OP what they want with a disclaimer that they should avoid the answer that you provide?

Comment: @Sudsy1002:  ...or you could answer it the way *you'd* approach the problem...without the caveats or short sidings. Heck, you could use this as an opportunity to demonstrate that while they *thought* they could get what they wanted with Approach A, Approach B is far better and actually more viable in situations like this.  But that's up to *you* as an answerer.